# Margin overflow when setting the geometry \AtBeginDocument

Tags: margins, geometry

Using the following minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={3.5cm,2.5cm}}

\AtBeginDocument{\geometry{vmargin={12cm,5cm}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Text on the first page overflows the lower margin. Other pages are fine, as illustrated by the figures below:

- first page margin (overflown)

[image: First page lower margin overflown]

- other pages (as expected)

[image: Other pages are behaving correctly]

I need to use commands in MWE for a complicated sequence (creating a complex template as a document class, calculating some lenghts involved in the template, then putting appropriate margins on the text block to fit into the template), so redefining MWE as an answer is probably not desirable.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem very clear to me. How would you like "Margin overflow when setting the geometry AtBeginDocument"?

Comment: You are right. And fancyhdr is not necessary either, so I will remove it from the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `\geometry` for a setting inside the text body. Use `\newgeometry` instead. However, `fancyhdr` should *always* be loaded *after* `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={3.5cm,2.5cm}}

\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{vmargin={12cm,5cm}}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```