# How to avoid text overflowing below bottom margin?

Tags: margins, geometry

My document contains a title page followed by some text. In order to create my title page, I have to change the page margins on the title page using `\newgeometry`, and after the title page I return to the usual default margins using `\restoregeometry`. It includes graphics, uses Tikz, and uses a new environment called `changemargin` whose code is placed at the beginning of the code before `\begin{document}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, titlepage, draft]{article}
% USING DRAFT BECAUSE WE DO NOT HAVE THE PDFs TO BE INCLUDED
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}% ADDED !!!!!

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
}%
\item[]}
{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newgeometry{left=6.75cm, right=1.25cm, top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm}

\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{8cm} 
\flushright \textbf{University of ...}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm} % your specified distance
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.5cm}
\flushright \includegraphics[width=2.50cm]{logo.pdf}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

\useasboundingbox [fill=blue!20] ($ (current page.south west) + (1, 1)  $) rectangle ($ (current page.north west) + (6.75, -1) $) ;
\draw [line width=0.01mm, blue] ($ (current page.north west) + (1, -1)  $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-1, 1) $) ; 
\draw ($ (current page.north west) + (9.625, -4.00)  $) -- ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.25, -4.00)  $) ;
\draw ($ (current page.south west) + (9.625, 4.00)  $) -- ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.25, 4.00)  $) ;

\node[anchor=south west, %anchor is upper left corner of the graphic
xshift=1.125cm, %shifting around
yshift=1.125cm]  
at (current page.south west) %left upper corner of the page
{\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{logo2.pdf}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{changemargin}{0cm}{-0.25cm}

\centering

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\rule{127mm}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}    
\rule{127mm}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large \textbf{Title}}\\[\baselineskip]
{ Subtitle}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\rule{127mm}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{127mm}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\end{changemargin}

\mbox{} \vfill \hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{8cm}
\flushright \textbf{Faculty of Science}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm} % your specified distance
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.5cm}
\flushright \includegraphics[width=2.50cm]{logo3.pdf}
\end{minipage}%

\restoregeometry

\end{titlepage}

\newpage

article text

\end{document}
```

However, the text on the first page overflows into the bottom margin of the document. This does not happen for all the other pages, only the first one.

What have I done wrong?

(I know my question is similar to this one:

[Margin overflow when setting the geometry \AtBeginDocument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/margin-overflow-when-setting-the-geometry-atbegindocument)

but the answer given there doesn't solve my problem.)

Comment: What kind of material goes inside `titlepage` (images, only text)? Can you please add it (you can use some dummy text) to your example code so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `\enlargethispage{amount}` in the title page instead of changing geometry?

Comment: I have combined your three code snippets into a single one, changed the class option from `final` to draft (because we do not have the pdfs to be included) and added `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. Now we have got a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (well, not so minimal, but it can be copied, pasted, and compiled).

Comment: Adding either `\geometry{showframe}` or `\usepackage{showframe}` after `\usepackage{geometry}` one gets frames around text/header/margin/footer. Where does the text flow into the bottom margin? Another thought: What about placing `\restoregeometry` *after* `\end{titlepage} \newpage`?

Comment: I believe the problem is that `\newgeometry` will affect the following page, so it needs to be moved to _before_ `\begin{titlepage}`. And you will probably want to move `\restoregeometry` to be _after_ `\end{ttilepage}`, before `\newpage`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter and Stephen : placing \newgeometry before \begin{titlepage} and \restoregeometry after \end{titlepage} did it !

Comment: @PeterGrill: Because the comment solved the problem, could you please post it as answer? To Percy: By using the "at username" that user automatically gets notified about the post (in this case Peter Grill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\newgeometry` affects the following page, so moving it to be *before* `\begin{titlepage}` will ensure that it effects the title page.

And since you probably want pages after the title page to have the original geometry, moving `\restoregeometry` to be after `\end{ttilepage}`, and before `\newpage` will make it effective on the first page of the document.

### Notes:

- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text.
- The `[showframe]` option was applied to [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry)
  was just to show the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, titlepage, draft]{article}
% USING DRAFT BECAUSE WE DO NOT HAVE THE PDFs TO BE INCLUDED
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}% ADDED !!!!!
\usepackage{showframe}% ADDED !!!!!
\usepackage{lipsum}% ADDED !!!!!

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
}%
\item[]}
{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=6.75cm, right=1.25cm, top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm}
\begin{titlepage}

%\newgeometry{left=6.75cm, right=1.25cm, top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm}

\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{8cm} 
\flushright \textbf{University of ...}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm} % your specified distance
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.5cm}
\flushright \includegraphics[width=2.50cm]{logo.pdf}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

\useasboundingbox [fill=blue!20] ($ (current page.south west) + (1, 1)  $) rectangle ($ (current page.north west) + (6.75, -1) $) ;
\draw [line width=0.01mm, blue] ($ (current page.north west) + (1, -1)  $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-1, 1) $) ; 
\draw ($ (current page.north west) + (9.625, -4.00)  $) -- ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.25, -4.00)  $) ;
\draw ($ (current page.south west) + (9.625, 4.00)  $) -- ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.25, 4.00)  $) ;

\node[anchor=south west, %anchor is upper left corner of the graphic
xshift=1.125cm, %shifting around
yshift=1.125cm]  
at (current page.south west) %left upper corner of the page
{\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{logo2.pdf}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{changemargin}{0cm}{-0.25cm}

\centering

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\rule{127mm}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}    
\rule{127mm}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large \textbf{Title}}\\[\baselineskip]
{ Subtitle}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\rule{127mm}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{127mm}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\end{changemargin}

\mbox{} \vfill \hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{8cm}
\flushright \textbf{Faculty of Science}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm} % your specified distance
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.5cm}
\flushright \includegraphics[width=2.50cm]{logo3.pdf}
\end{minipage}%

\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\newpage

\lipsum[1-12]% Added

\end{document}
```